# Can we access list from different site collection using SPService JQuery?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, spservices

I want to read list from different site collection. Is there any way to do this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the sample successfully tested with SPServices JQuery 2014.01:

```
        $().SPServices({
        operation: "GetListItems",
        // Force sync so that we have the right values for the child column onchange trigger
        async: false,
        webURL: "/webs/sitecollection/site",
        listName: "tst",
        // Filter based on the currently selected parent column's value
        // Only get the parent and child columns
        CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Title' /></ViewFields>",
        // Override the default view rowlimit and get all appropriate rows
        CAMLRowLimit: 0,
        completefunc: function(xData, Status) {
            window.alert(Status);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanx, but it wont work if list is from different site collection.

Comment: I have double checked it and it works fine. I did two tests. One read data from webs/sitecoll/site on root sitecoll. Then I read items from webs/sitecoll/site on root site of webs/sitecoll2. Both worked well. Use fiddler tool to see raw response. It contains more details why the call failed. I guess permissions.

Comment: hello @Mazin , Thanx for great help.... you are saying its working for you , Great :) !!  may i need to do with some site collection level settings. Can you please suggest what settings need to be done ?

Comment: I did tests on new almost empty sitecollections and sites without any special settings. Try to examine the return value of the call by fiddler to know error message. Without the error message it's just guessing what could be wrong.

Comment: Thanx Mazin .... Thank you so much for your help. It was silly mistake by me, permissions set on Spservice jquery. Now its working fine. You are Great @Mazin :)

Comment: @JanVanek, I am getting unauthorized exception while doing with your solution. What could be the possible work around for this? Account that I am using is Administrator for both the site collections.